# Do chemicals undergo granular convection?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Do chemicals of an average weight, such as Polyethylene Glycols, undergo granular convection (the Brazil nut effect)?

Comment: Good question; is ultracentrifugation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultracentrifuge, affected by *size* of molecules, as well as mass?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik is it?